# Make select options disable after submitting the form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, sticky

I've been trying this for awhile. I appreciate your help.

I've a form with two fields. 1- Username. 2- City.

Users can select their cities from the city select options (the cities come from the database).

However, if the user didn't find his/her city, he/she can check the checkbox to enable a text input to enter his/her city (and at the same time the select options will be disable).

The issue is, if the user writes new city, the select options will be disable (this is good), but when the user submits the form a and there was a validation issue (for example: empty username!), the form will go back with the following:

The city select options will be enable !!

The city text input will be disable (with sticky city name that the user entered) !!

So, how can I keep the city name in the text input enable with the value, and make the city select options disable??

This is my code:

```
<title> Form </title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/icon/anta_ana.png">

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
<!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ie8.css" /><![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ie9.css" /><![endif]-->
```

```
<div id="page-wrapper">

        <?php
            if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
                $username = $_POST['username'];
                $city_name = $_POST['city_name'];

                //errors handling :
                $error = array();
                if(empty($username)) $error[]= "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible input-sm' role='alert' dir='rtl' style='padding-top: 5px; padding-right: -5px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px'>
                                                                                    <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>
                                                                                    <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>
                                                                                    </button>
                                                                                    <strong style='color: #e62e00;'>Warning!</strong> Please write your name!
                                                                                    </div>";
                if($city_name == 'all') $error[]= "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible input-sm' role='alert' dir='rtl' style='padding-top: 5px; padding-right: -5px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px'>
                                                                                    <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>
                                                                                    <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>
                                                                                    </button>
                                                                                    <strong style='color: #e62e00;'>Warning!</strong> Please selects a city!
                                                                                    </div>";
                if(empty($error)) {
                    include("dbc.php");
                    $q = "INSERT INTO users (username,
                                                                    city_name) VALUES
                                                                    ('$username',
                                                                    '$city_name')";
                    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
                    if($r){
                        echo "<script>window.open('successfully_registered.php', '_self')</script>";
                    }
                    else{
                        echo "error";
                    }
                }
                else{
                    foreach ($error as $err){
                        echo $err;
                    }
                }
            }
        ?>

        <form action="question.php" method="POST" name="" dir="rtl">

            <!-- Userame -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" style="float: right;"> Username </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" value =
                <?php if(isset($_POST['username'])) echo $_POST['username'] ?>>
            </div>

            <!-- City -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label style="float: right;">City </label>
                <?php
                    include("dbc.php");
                    $qm = "SELECT DISTINCT city_name FROM cities ORDER BY city_name";
                    $rm = mysqli_query($dbc,$qm);
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rm)){
                        $cities_array[] = $row['city_name'];
                    }
                    echo '<select class="form-control border-input" name="city_name" id="city_name">';
                    echo '<option value="all"> All </option>';
                    foreach($cities_array as $cities){
                        $selected = '';
                        if($_POST['city_name'] == $cities) {
                            $selected = 'selected="selected"';
                        }
                        echo '<option value="'.$cities.'"'.$selected.'>'.$cities.'</option>';
                    }
                    echo '</select>';
                ?>
            </div>

            <!-- Another City? -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Didn't find you city? Check this box to enter your city: <input type="checkbox" id="another_city"/>
                <input placeholder="Write your city here" class="form-control" type="text" name="new_city" id="new_city" disabled value =
                "<?php if (isset($_POST['new_city'])) echo $_POST['new_city']; ?>" >
                <script>
                    document.getElementById('another_city').onchange = function() {
                        document.getElementById('new_city').disabled = !this.checked;
                        if(document.getElementById('new_city').disabled){
                            $("#city_name").prop('disabled', false);
                        }
                        else{
                            $("#city_name").prop('disabled', true);
                        }
                    };
                </script>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-fill form-control" name="submit" value="Send"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> Send </button>
            </div>

        </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to disable Select just use this code

```
 $('select').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Comment: I want to disable it ONLY if the city name input is enable (and make sure it doesn't go back to enable after I submit the form). I'll try it. Thanks

Comment: city name input is your Textbox?

Comment: you want to disable your select option when user enter cities rite?

Comment: Yes. For now they work good when I check the checkbox to write a city name. But when I submit the form, the city text input go back disable and the select options go back enable !!

Comment: Yes I want to disable the select option when I enter a city name, and keep it disable even if I submit the form. Because for now the select option becomes disable when I write a city name, but once I submit the form, the select options becomes enable, and the text input becomes disable!

Comment: When you are submitting your form. in Success of your form submission add enable to your textbox and disable to select the same way i share above

Comment: Can you please show me how in my code above. I appreciate your help.

Comment: **$("#myform").bind('ajax:complete', function() {    
   });**     give your form an Id and use this method. and inside this method just make your  select disable and your INPUTE enabled

Comment: i dont know about PHP i m a donNet developer :) i am sharing my idea about your problem

Answer (score 0):

first of all: your code is (principally) vulnerable to sql injection,
http://php.net/manual/de/security.database.sql-injection.php

second: the reason is fairly simple, you submit your form, check it in the BACKEND and redirect. The reason why option is enabled and textbox disabled is simply because the page is reloaded, and thats your default setting. you could pass a parameter indicating the failure in your url (like err=wrongArgument) or whatever) and disable the options box with javascript in that case.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can you please explain your solution within the code. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem only occurs because of validation you can first submit the form details via an ajax request. validate it and if there are no errors then submit them. If you were using jquery then you could do something like

```
$("#form-id").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'validate.php',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(res){
                    if(res == "success") {
                        $(this).submit();
                    } else { // error }
                },
                fail: function(){
                    // error
                }
            })
})
```

one other thing that you could do is if you redirect to the current page after validation fails and pass a query string at the end that denotes that the user checked the checkbox or not. you have to give your checkbox a name for this so it gets submitted over as well when you submit the form.

```
if(isset($_POST['another_city']) and $_POST['another_city'] == "on") {
    // header("Location: ...") redirects the page to the provided location
    header("Location: question.php?checked=1"&city=".$city_name);
}
```

once you do this you will have to add code to check whether the `$_GET['checked']` and `$_GET['city']` are set or not. if they are set then you can set the provided values in the form using js like:

php:

```
$checked = "";
$city = "";
if(isset($_GET['checked']) and $_GET['checked'] == 1) {
    $checked = "checked";
}
if(isset($_GET['city'])) {
    $city= $_GET['city'];
}
```

html:

```
 <div class="form-group">
     <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Didn't find you city? Check this box to enter your city: <input type="checkbox" <?php echo $checked?> id="another_city"/>
     <input placeholder="Write your city here" class="form-control" type="text" name="new_city" id="new_city" disabled value = "<?php echo $city; ?>" >
```

Comment: Yes. The problem happens only when there is a validation issue. I guess the options will go back to the default. Because the default is the select options is enable and the text input is disable. Is there another solution with the same javascript code that I'm using? Because I'm not familiar with ajax. Thank you :)

Comment: well without ajax you could either use the 2nd option i mentioned or validate on the client side with js/jquery. i dont recommend validating on the client side if its in production but for a school project or practice it should be fine.

Comment: So, where should I put this line (header("Location: index.php?checked=".$checked."&city=".$city_name)
) in the head ??